# Tengo un problema para centrar un input

Tags: css, input

Estaba practicando html y css y me encontre con un problema al momento de querer centrar un input.
Aqui el codigo en HTML y CSS.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;

}

form{
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: block;
    background-color: #555;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50% ;
    text-align: center;
}

input{
    padding: 6px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sen&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Inserte su nombre aquí">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a resolverlo, ya que por mas que revise, no entendi que estaba pasando.

[image: Aqui el problema del que hablo, no se centra por completo en el form]

Comment: Agrega `display: flex;` al `form`. Eso resolverá tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

si cambias el "display:block" por "display:flex" al elemento form, se queda perfecto!

```
form{
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #555;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50% ;
    text-align: center;
}
```